# Create Report Template Sheets and Populate With Data based on Date and Time

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet of raw data that includes vehicle counts over multiple days. Each date is a row representing vehicle counts taken during a 60 minute period (so 24 rows per day). 
I have a model that creates a new sheet using the report template for each day. I just can't figure out how to get the actual vehicle count data for each day to populate each sheet for each hour. 
 Each new tab that is created is named for the date. If we have vehicle counts for 8 day then 8 new tabs would be created. Within that new tab I need to be able to take all 24 vehicle counts and paste them into the template report in the appropriate cells.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SheetsFromTemplate()
Dim wsMASTER As Worksheet, wsTEMP As Worksheet, wasVISIBLE As Boolean
Dim shDates As Range, Item As Range, NmStr As String

'keep focus in this workbook
With ThisWorkbook
     'sheet to be copied                           
    Set wsTEMP = .Sheets("Template")             
    'check if it's hidden or not    
     wasVISIBLE = (wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetVisible) 
    'make it visible           
    If Not wasVISIBLE Then wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetVisible      

    'sheet with dates and data
    Set wsMASTER = .Sheets("Raw Data")             

    'range to find names to be checked
    Set shDates = wsMASTER.Range("C9:C" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlConstants)   

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'check one data at a time                 
    For Each Item In shDates                        
        NmStr = FixStringForSheetName(CStr(Item.Text))
        'if sheet does not exist...
        If Not Evaluate("ISREF('" & NmStr & "'!A1)") Then
            '...create it from template  
            wsTEMP.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)  
            '...rename it 
            ActiveSheet.Name = NmStr                        
        End If

    Next Item

    'return to the master sheet
    wsMASTER.Activate  
    'hide the template if necessary                                         
    If Not wasVISIBLE Then wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetHidden   
    'update screen one time at the end   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True                           

End With


MsgBox "All Reports created"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without seeing your worksheets (layout/position of data), but something like the below might give you an idea on how to achieve what you're after.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SheetsFromTemplate()

    Dim templateSheet As Worksheet
    Set templateSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")

    Dim originalSheetState As XlSheetVisibility
    originalSheetState = templateSheet.Visible

    'sheet with dates and data
    Dim masterSheet As Worksheet
    Set masterSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")

    templateSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible

    Dim lastRowOnMasterSheet As Long
    lastRowOnMasterSheet = masterSheet.Cells(masterSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Assert lastRowOnMasterSheet >= 9

    'range to find names to be checked
    Dim datesToLoopThrough As Range
    Set datesToLoopThrough = masterSheet.Range("C9:C" & lastRowOnMasterSheet)

    Dim toFilterIncludingHeaders As Range
    Set toFilterIncludingHeaders = datesToLoopThrough.Offset(-1).Resize(datesToLoopThrough.Rows.Count + 1)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'check one data at a time
    Dim item As Range
    For Each item In datesToLoopThrough

        Dim nmStr As String
        nmStr = FixStringForSheetName(CStr(item.Text))

        ' The IF condition below might be problematic if sheet
        ' already exists, but has not yet had dates
        ' transferred/copy-pasted to it.
        If Not DoesWorksheetExist(nmStr) Then
            With CreateSheetFromTemplate(templateSheet)
                .Name = nmStr
                .Move After:=.Parent.Worksheets(.Parent.Worksheets.Count)

                toFilterIncludingHeaders.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=item
                Intersect(datesToLoopThrough.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow, mastersheet.range("D:Q")).Copy .Range("F13") ' You haven't shown your template sheet, so don't know where to paste to.
            End With
        End If
    Next item

    masterSheet.Activate
    templateSheet.Visible = originalSheetState

    'update screen one time at the end
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "All Reports created"
End Sub

Private Function CreateSheetFromTemplate(ByVal someTemplateSheet As Worksheet) As Worksheet
    ' Creates a copy of template sheet and returns an object reference to the newly created sheet.
    ' Newly created sheet is at index 1 (for deterministic/reliability reasons).
    ' Call site can name/move as needed.
    someTemplateSheet.Copy Before:=someTemplateSheet.Parent.Worksheets(1)
    Set CreateSheetFromTemplate = someTemplateSheet.Parent.Worksheets(1)
End Function

Private Function DoesWorksheetExist(ByVal sheetNameToCheck As String) As Boolean
    ' Checks if sheet of a given name exists in ThisWorkbook.
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetNameToCheck)
    On Error GoTo 0
    DoesWorksheetExist = Not (targetSheet Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! This is so close. Sorry, realize it is difficult to know for sure without seeing my worksheets. The only thing I can't figure out now is how to copy only certain columns from the Raw Data and paste it into another specific range on each daily report. This example copies the entire row and paste into A9. For each date, I would like to copy "D:Q" from the raw data and paste into ("F13:S36") in the new sheets created from the template. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: @LSpear Sorry, on phone at the moment, so can't test. But have edited my answer to reflect your comment. Hopefully it should work if you want to try again.